# How to get oozie coordinator id in the workflow?

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

My requirement is to kill or stop coordinator which initiated a workflow in case any workflow action fails.

wf:id gives the id for the workflow.

is there any such fuction for coord??

if not, please suggest ways to pass coord it to workflow.

Answer (score 3):

You can use coord:actionId in your coordinator and pass it to the workflow like this:

```
<coordinator-app>
...........

<action>
    <workflow>
        <app-path>${oozieApplicationPath}</app-path>

        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>coordId</name>
                <value>${coord:actionId()}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </workflow>
</action>
```

This will give you something like this: 0000043-151201101920761-oozie-oozi-C@1, which is coordinatorId@actionId.

Comment: Where is this actually documented? I can't find it in the oozie documentation.